# Sentiment Analysis using NLTK

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, opennlp

If you were to do sentiment analysis on reviews text using NLTK in python what would be the high level steps to be followed. There are so many terms in NLTK like stemming, parts of speech to name a few, but I would like to know a high level approach for processing text.

Comment: You are basically asking someone to summarize techniques from an active area of research in NLP in a stackoverflow post. Your best bet is to check google scholar for the relevant literature and see if it meets your needs. If you have access to ACM here is a start: http://cacm.acm.org/magazines/2013/4/162501-techniques-and-applications-for-sentiment-analysis/fulltext

Comment: NLTK tutorial: https://github.com/hb20007/hands-on-nltk-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

At a high level here are the "standard" steps to doing sentiment analysis (which is really just a form of text classification), and this is my opinion based on my experience, not exhaustive, but it will give you some buzzwords and a basic flow as a point of departure for deeper research:

1. Somehow you need to generate some labeled samples of text. This can be done by hand ( a spreadsheet with two columns, "LABEL' and "THE_TEXT" for instance. Samples can often be generated automatically, depending on your data. You'll usually need at least hundreds of samples per class label.
2. You will need to pick a "Feature extraction" or "Feature Engineering" method that makes sense for your data. A simple approach is to use a "Bag of words"...meaning just feed the training api the raw text. Typically you will soon see this is really not good enough, and you'll tinker with things like stemming, lemmatization, and NGrams in order to capture more context and get better natural groupings in your data. This part can get really complicated if you are working with multi language corpora.
3. Train the model. I'm not familiar with NLTK, but typically you pass in your text samples with labels, and the feature extraction is part of the training routine in general. At the end of this step, you will have a model in the form of a file, that you load into an instance of a classifier.
4. Use the classifier (which is using your shiny new model) to classify your data. Key here is you have to use the EXACT same feature extraction technique you used to train the model on your data at classification time or you will be comparing apples to oranges.
5. The classifier will likely return a distribution over whatever your categories are (the labels) with some kind of scores. You then use this data however you want. This can be powerful and exciting.

Hope this helps... text classification has many nuances, so each step above can mutate based on your data and what you're trying to get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

To perform sentiment analysis on reviews text, any text for that matter, we need to extract the features first. It depends on the user to what level you need to extract the features.
Well-known model to achieve this is Bag of Words.

There are a few steps on the high-level of processing text.

1. Tokenizing: It is a process of shortening or splitting, an article into smaller forms, maybe smaller paragraphs or sentences or words or letters.

   Ex: You look very happy. → [‘You’, ‘look’, ‘very’, ‘happy’]
2. Stop Words: The words that do not contribute to any information in the article are referred to as stop words. These are mostly prepositions, articles, conjunctions etc.,

   Ex: Book is placed on the table. Stop Words = [‘is’, ‘on’, ‘the’]
3. Stemming: It is a process of stemming the words to their root forms by removing prefixes and suffixes.

   Ex: slowly → slow

After processing your text through these methods you are good to calculate sentiment of the text. Although these are high-level and not exhaustive methods for processing text. 
There are many resources available that might suggest you more methods in feature extraction NLP.